# backdrop-filter blur stops working as soon as border-radius is applied to the DIV

Tags: blur, css-filters, backdrop

Strangely, it started happening since Chrome94 and only on my Android phone (*while everywhere else it still works fine like in my Android tablet*).
When `border-radius: 30px;` is removed from the class that has `backdrop-filter: blur(8px);` in it, the DIV now appears with the default sharp corners (*that we don't want*) but the glassmorphism actually goes back to functioning as expected and the great look starts working again on the phone as well. So the question is,

> Is there a way to make the beautiful `backdrop-filter: blur()` work without sacrificing the beauty of rounded corners?

Already tried and **failed**, using pseudo elements like `::before` but the result is the exact same.

Also tried and **failed** applying `filter: blur(0px);` to the underlying element that is supposed to get blurred but that changed absolutely nothing in my tests.

Note 1: No problems observed on Windows PC Chrome and ASUS tablet Chrome.
Note 2: It used to work fine on the SONY phone too before updating to Chrome94 *(that is if my memory is correct)*